# How to iterate over unique elements in an array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

Suppose I have the following array:

```
int arr[7] = {18,16,5,5,18,16,4}
```

**How can I iterate over unique elements(18, 16, 5 and 4) in a loop in the same order in which they occur?**

I could use a [set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) but then the order of the iteration would change(set stores elements in ascending order).

**What is the fastest solution to this problem?**

Comment: If the values are in a known limited range, you can use a lookup table. Create an array with bool elements, sized to the maximum value. Use the values of the first array as index into the bool array.

Comment: `std::bitset` also comes to mind. Slightly slower than `bool` array, but more space efficient.

Comment: @zett42 I think a bool array would be better because it is also easier to implement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate over the array and store the numbers you have already seen in a set. For each iteration you check whether the number is already in the set or not. If yes, skip the current element. If not, process it and insert it into the set.

Also note that you want an `std::unordered_set` and not a `std::set` which is ordered. Order doesn't matter for your filtering set.

Comment: Is there a faster solution?

Comment: @Agile_Eagle It is possible a `std::vector` could be used in place of a `std::set` which might give some performance gain but adding unique, ordered elements to a `std::vector` is more complicated than just using a `std::set`.

Comment: @Galik how do you add unique ordered element to vector?

Comment: @Agile_Eagle This (not well tested) code is intended to do just that. https://gitlab.com/Galik/header-only/blob/master/hol/vector_utils.h But I suggest timing each method. Also consider using an `std::unordered_set`. See which gives better performance in your situation.

Answer (score 1):

If the values are in a known limited range, you can use a lookup table. Create an array with `bool` elements, sized to maximum value + 1. Use the values of the first array as index into the bool array.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int arr[7] = {18,16,5,5,18,16,4};

    constexpr int maxValue = 18;
    bool lookup[maxValue + 1]{};

    for( auto i : arr )
    {
        if( ! lookup[ i ] )
        {
            std::cout << i << ' ';
            lookup[ i ] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3176a43109f42c24)

A [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) would be more space efficient but also slower, because individual bits cannot be directly addressed by the CPU.

Simply replace the bool array like so:

```
std::bitset<maxValue + 1> lookup;
```

The remaining code stays the same.

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/afa6f7af82d59acc)